# Sed command for deleting a line based on the next line

Tags: text-processing, sed

Please share the `sed` command to delete a line based on the two line string.

For example I have the text below:

```
AAAAA
BBBBBB
 aaa 
bbb
 USING INDEX
)
aaaa
 USING INDEX
        TABLESPACE IDX_TAB3
)
```

If a line contains `USING INDEX` and the next line contains `)` then it should get deleted.
In this I have to delete the 5th line alone but it should not delete the 8th line. The output should be like below:

```
AAAAA
BBBBBB 
aaa 
bbb
)
aaaa
 USING INDEX
  TABLESPACE IDX_TAB3
)
```

Comment: Does the answer have to be based on `sed` or are other command-line-based text-processing tools permitted?

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain a rolling two-line buffer, printing the first line only if it doesn't match your two-line pattern:

```
$ sed ':a; $!N; /USING INDEX.*\n.*)/!P; D; ba' file
AAAAA
BBBBBB
 aaa
bbb
)
aaaa
 USING INDEX
        TABLESPACE IDX_TAB3
)
```

Note that the above allows for zero or more trailing characters after the `USING INDEX` pattern and zero or more leading characters before the `)` - if your input is representative i.e. there is a newline immediately after `USING INDEX`, followed immediately by the parenthesis, then you could simplify that to

```
sed ':a; $!N; /USING INDEX\n)/!P; D; ba' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script does the trick:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
(NR>1 && !(index($0, ")") && index(last, "USING INDEX"))) {
  print last;
}

{
  last=$0;
}

END{
  print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/USING INDEX/ {this=$0; getline; if (! /^[[:blank:]]*\)/) print this} 1'
```